# Label files on rootfs (ramdisk) with SELinux context

Tags: android, selinux

how are SELinux labels applied to files on the rootfs, i.e. file residing directly in `/` that do not belong to the `system`, `data` ... partitions (Android 7.1)? A call to `ls -lZ /` on adb yields (excerpt):

```
-rwxr-x---   1 root   root   u:object_r:init_exec:s0         806748 1970-01-01 01:00 init
drwxr-xr-x  14 root   root   u:object_r:cgroup:s0                 0 2019-03-14 14:01 acct
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   u:object_r:rootfs:s0             99904 1970-01-01 01:00 file_contexts.bin
```

According to my research, rootfs (GPIO+GZ) does not support SElinux context labeling (no xattr), so all files should have the same context, which apparently is not the case. I have added a custom file `/foo` to the ramdisk which inherits the default context `u:object_r:rootfs:s0`.

As a test, I have added a rule to `system/sepolicy/file_contexts`:

```
/foo   u:object_r:init_exec:s0
```

to give my file the same context as `/init`. This does have any affect (yet `grep /foo /file_contexts.bin` shows that `/file_contexts.bin` was updated). How do I label `/foo`?

Comment: I think you looking for `semanage fcontext` that can be used to make permanent changes in file labeling. Then `restorecon reset _filename_` will set the file label. This is how it work on rhel. I am not sure about android.

Comment: These modify the extended file attributes, but the rootfs doesn't have those. I think init labels them on every boot.

Comment: It does on rhel, `semanage fcontext --list | grep "^/[a-zA-Z0-9]* "` this show you the root fs and its folders default contexts. without grep you get the entire list but that a very long one.

Comment: Well then rhel uses a different root file system. The CPIO archive used for the ramdisk does not support extended attributes.

Comment: I see , sorry then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. First, the file contexts are declared (as for all other files) in the [file_contexts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r6/private/file_contexts) file, which gets compiled and put into the rootfs as `/file_contexts.bin`. The `/init` binary then performs some [hardcoded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r6/init/selinux.cpp#454) [calls](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r6/init/selinux.cpp#534) to `restorecon` to apply these labels to some files and directories. Further calls to `restorecon` are made from the [`init*.rc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r6/rootdir/init.rc#20) file(s) to apply some more file labels.

So, to add a label to a custom file on the rootfs, it needs to be defined the file_contexts file and a call to `restorecon` needs to be put into either the `init` source code or one of the `init*.rc` files.